# angularjs $http response data as readStream to Aliyun OSS?

Tags: angularjs, xmlhttprequest

I want to download an image file through `XHR` using the `$http` service provided by angularJS, and upload the response data (image data) to OSS(it is a service that host files provided by Alibaba)  and it's [api reference for put](https://github.com/ali-sdk/ali-oss#putname-file-options) is:

[image]

which indicates that it will take a `{String|Buffer|ReadStream}` as the second parameter `file`, 
but how can I transfer the response data so that I could make that a parameter for this `put(name, file)` method like:

```
$http.get("http://image.url/file.gif").then(
    function success(response){
        console.log("type of response.data is :" + typeof response.data);
        oss.put("test.jpg", response.data); //<-- here will give an error
    },
    function fail(response){
       console.log("error");
    }
)
```

this will give a type error:

[image]
Any suggestion or answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if you're getting the images via links all the time and you want to get the string data out of it, I've tried a small function that i hope it helps, it takes the link and puts to you the image data in base64 string format

```
function getBase64StringFromImgLink(imageSrc, imgType) {

  var imageAsCanvas;

  /*
   * Creates a new image object from the src
   * Uses the deferred pattern
   */
  var createImage = function () {
      var deferred = $.Deferred();
      var img = new Image();

      img.onload = function() {
          deferred.resolve(img);
      };
      img.src = imageSrc;
      return deferred.promise();
  };

  /*
   * Create an Image, when loaded and start to resize
   */
  $.when(createImage()).then(function (image) {
        imageAsCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        imageAsCanvas.width = image.width;
        imageAsCanvas.height = image.height;
        var ctx = imageAsCanvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, imageAsCanvas.width, imageAsCanvas.height);

        $scope.$apply(function($scope){
          $scope.imageAsBase64String = imageAsCanvas.toDataURL(imgType);
          oss.put("test.jpg", $scope.imageAsBase64String); //<-- here will be the data string i hope it works
        });
    }, function () {console.log('error creating an image')});
}
//How to call example
getBase64StringFromImgLink('images/george-avatar.jpg', 'image/jpeg');

<!--HTML -->
<img data-ng-src="{{imageAsBase64String}}" >
```

Comment: thanks for answering, unfortunately, the image I want to fetch and upload is a `gif`, which in this case seems, retrieving data from canvas won't help, thanks though :-)

Comment: np, sorry it didn't help :)